# Medium scale repeated tasks in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cron

I'm building a web app that tracks stats for a game. The API for that game (Steam Web API) only allows me to retrieve data from the most recently played match.

When a user requests their stats to be tracked, I need make a call to the Steam Web API every 10 minutes or so to check if they have played another match, then store it in the database if they have. The problem is, I check every 10 minutes for *every* user...

Is there a way to schedule this efficiently so that the server doesn't get overloaded? This application could potentially server 10,000+ users.

Please feel free to correct anything in this question if I got something obviously wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many gems for recurring events in ruby, like:

- [ice cube](https://github.com/seejohnrun/ice_cube)
- [recurrence](https://github.com/fnando/recurrence)

However, if you are going to have lots of users, and you are worried about server load, I would suggest not using your rails app to do this.

Instead, build another service which doesn't run on your rails app to update your database with statistics.

Having an independent service like this decoupled from your main app allows you to easily put it on another server, and/or have it scale independently from your webapp.